# AS3 get/set vs. reassigning the value

Tags: actionscript-3, get, set, getter-setter

What's the purpose of getting/setting values when you can just reassign the value? Is it just because you can get/set private variables?

Answer (score 1):

Using getters and setters is the same as having a method that reassigns a passed value, except it is a formal way of doing it. When you have a getter/setter, the programmer will have expectations on how it will work. Usually they have no major side-effects.

Also refer to this question - [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) - for reasons why to use getters and setters at all.